# How to step through excel(xlsx) file uploaded in a BLOB field mssql

Tags: sql-server, excel, blob

I need to get values from a certain column in a xlsx spreadsheet that was uploaded to my database in a image(blob) field. I would like to step through the rows and get values from say column 4 and insert the values into another table by using sqlserver. I can to it with CSV files by casting the image field to varbinary and then cast it again to varhar and search for ','s.

Can openrowset work on a blob field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt that this can work. Even though the data in the XLSX is stored in Microsofts Office Open-XML format (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML) the XML is then zipped which means that your XLSX file is a binary file. So if you want to access data in the xlsx (can't you use csv instead?) I think you need to do so programmatically. Depending on the programming logic of your choice there are various open-source projects allowing you to access xlsx file.

- Java: Apache POI http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/
- C++: http://sourceforge.net/projects/xlslib/?source=directory
- ...